# how to get correct path of application

Tags: php

I want to show exact path of my index.php
this my code

```
<code>
  <?php
     $code='<iframe width="100%" height="180px" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no"  src="//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'"></iframe>';

     echo htmlentities($code);
  ?>
</code>
```

It's output path is

> "//newsletter.themerakimagazine.com/newsletter/mail"

I want to remove just /mail from path

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: _"i want to show exact path of my index.php"_ - And where is that file located? In the folder `newsletter` or in the document root? Or do you have multiple index.php files? Then which one do you want?

Comment: @BhaveshTailor relying on document root is a little risky as it can be misleading in some configurations. e.g. setting a user path in apache. Most reliable way for flexible code is to have as a config, but provide a prompt based on DOCUMENT_ROOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or of you just want to remove mail then use

```
$url = explode('/', "//newsletter.themerakimagazine.com/newsletter/mail");
array_pop($url);
echo implode('/', $url);
```

Check and let me know if it;s work

Comment: And if the URL is `"//newsletter.themerakimagazine.com/newsletter/mail/more"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_url()` function，You can try